# How to solve EmergencyData app appearing on Huawei Ascend G630?

Tags: huawei

My Huawei Ascend G630 (G630-U00) only shows an app titled EmergencyData with 2 options and 1 button, all in Chinese.

[image: the screenshot of EmergencyData app in Chinese with 2 options and 1 button]

I can't do anything to close this app or continue using the phone.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The Chinese text roughly says,

> The system has detected a corrupted internal storage, please choose from the following operations:
>
> Factory reset
>
> Reboot to this interface

At this point your best bet is to choose Factory reset (wiping your data in the process), click the confirm button down-right, and hope it does its job. If it doesn't, the storage hardware is likely broken and requires taking the phone to repairs.

Answer (score -2):

This is a hardware error.Replace and change the EMMC.